# Update a String Attribute in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to update a string attribute in the database.

I tried using update_attribute but it isn't working. It works for integer attributes but not for String attributes.

How do i solve this ?

**EDIT**

code example:

```
@post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
@comment = @post.comments.create!(params[:comment])
@comment.update_attribute(:commenter,User.find_by_id(session[:user_id]).name)
```

Comment: You're doing something wrong. This answer is as specific as your question.

Comment: Could you post a code example?

Comment: added the code to the original post...

Comment: What is the error message, if any? What value is returned in the find statement? Could `name` be `nil`?

Comment: yea name is nil. Its not setting it to the userid from the session. but if i use the same(User.find_by_id(session[:user_id]).name) on a view page, I get the username.

Comment: What does your model look like?

Comment: Could it be a naming issue? Under the traditional Railsy naming scheme, the column would be called :user_id.

Comment: maybe your session is define after this line ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, is there any reason you save the name as a string in the database? Normally you would go through the association to get the name.

```
@comment.user.name
```

I would really suggest you add a user_id to the comments table and then use:

```
@comment.user = User.find_by_id(session[:user_id])
```

or

```
@comment.update_attribute(:user_id, session[:user_id])
```

to update the commenter.